# Amazon Mechanical Turk: Created a Job using website UI, but would like to accept/reject jobs using the Python API

Tags: mechanicalturk

I created a data collection Job (HITs) using the mechanical turk website. 
I would like to reject/approve jobs using python API, because that would accelerate the process.

I can approve the process using the python API, but that doesn't update the Assignment status on the website. Does anyone have any idea on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, HITs created through the website are not visible or manageable in the UI (and vice-versa). So, that's why you can't see or operate on them via API calls. You'll need to create the HITs

You can reuse the layouts created in the website, though. Check out this article: https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-using-the-mturk-requester-website-together-with-python-and-boto-4a7ef0264b7e